TensorFlow error: defining a type within 'offsetof' is a Clang extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-offsetof-extensions]
I'm new to this.
Trying to build the Selective Framework for iOS using the below command -
bash tensorflow/lite/ios/build_frameworks.sh
--input_models=model1.tflite,model2.tflite
--target_archs=x86_64,armv7,arm64

But getting the error -
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_tonmoy/d1033cf820cfe9e8569d67cf059cb6df/external/upb/BUILD:57:11: Compiling upb/upb.c [for tool] failed: (Exit 1): wrapped_clang failed: error executing command (from target @upb//:upb) external/local_config_cc/wrapped_clang '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1' ... (remaining 32 arguments skipped)

external/upb/upb/upb.c:192:10: error: defining a type within 'offsetof' is a Clang 
extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-offsetof-extensions]

192 | n &= ~(upb_alignof(upb_arena) - 1);

  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/upb/upb/upb.c:183:37: note: expanded from macro 'upb_alignof'

183 | #define upb_alignof(type) offsetof (struct { char c; type member; }, member)

  |                                     ^~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/16/include/__stddef_offsetof.h:16:43: note: expanded from macro 'offsetof'

16 | #define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)

  |                                           ^
1 error generated.

Error in child process '/usr/bin/xcrun'. 1

Target //tensorflow/lite/ios/tmp:TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps_framework failed to build

Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.

INFO: Elapsed time: 218.346s, Critical Path: 17.92s

INFO: 4162 processes: 747 internal, 3415 local.

FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

How to fix this issue, Im very beginner to this issue. What could be the reason.
